# How to create button that updates a model's attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Normally I have this form to update a photo:

```
<% form_for(@proto, :url=>{:controller=>"protos", :action=>"update"}, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :image_data %>
        <%= submit_tag "Save Proto" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

It asks a user to put in the base64 string of an image data, and updates the image for the proto model.

**I have the image displayed on my site.**

Instead of the user copying and then pasting the base64 string; I just want to have a button that uses the source of that image(button will be under the image), to update @proto's image.

Can anyone point me to the right way? *Thanks.*

---

Comment: Your question is confusing now because you've done a lot of it and then asked different questions etc: the reader has to follow a complicated narrative, which is difficult.  If you change it to just be a simple question about the one thing you have left to do it will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.

I recycled the form and just auto-populated the text field with the image's source.

Achieved it by having javasript do:

```
document.getElementById("proto_image_data").value = 
document.getElementById("thecanvas").src;
```

proto_image_data is the id of the text field where it asks for :image_data, eg.

> 

thecanvas is the img id of the image I have on the page.

This is inside a javascript function that reveals the image and the form on the same page/div. Cheers.

Unfortunately, there is still a text field below the image(now with the image source ready to be updated). But, this at least achieved the main goal of not letting the user copy+paste the image source manually.

If there are better ways to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

---

Furthermore, I have replaced the text field into a hidden field and the script worked the same. The form is now invisible but the Submit button.